# How to handle files having spaces in Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

In my AWS S3 bucket there are so many files having spaces in between the file name. Here are 3 of those file URLs, which are accessible.

1. s3-us-west-amazonaws.com/debesh.com/images/natural+scenery+with+mountain+and+cloud.jpg
2. s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/debesh.com/images/natural+scenery+leaves+with+red+and+green+color.jpg
3. s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/debesh.com/images/natural+scenery+ant+in+the+middle+of+the+road+.jpg

But recently when I have implemented CloudFront CDN distribution which origin server is the above AWS S3 bucket.

My CloudFront domain name: d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net

Now when I am trying to access those images using my CloudFront domain name. I am getting an error page.

Here are the URL replaced by the CloudFront Domain Name:

1. d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural+scenery+with+mountain+and+cloud.jpg
2. d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural+scenery+leaves+with+red+and+green+color.jpg
3. d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural+scenery+ant+in+the+middle+of+the+road+.jpg

I have figure out that the issue is with the spaces between the file name.

CloudFront CDN is not recognizing + symbol (which is the space) between the file name.

**When I convert the "+" to "%20"**, it is displaying the images properly.

1. d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural%20scenery%20with%20mountain%20and%20cloud.jpg
2. d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural%20scenery%20leaves%20with%20red%20and%20green%20color.jpg
3. d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural%20scenery%20ant%20in%20the%20middle%20of%20the%20road%20.jpg

But the issue is that I have so many files like the above 3 files in my AWS S3 Bucket and I am not in a state to change the + sign into %20 sign.

**So could anyone suggest me a way I could handle these spaces between these file name**?

**Or does AWS CloudFront provide any tools to handle this type of file naming issue?**

Comment: have you tired encoding the url? I think the space gets converted to %20 when encoded (not sure if this will help in your situation)

Comment: This is interesting, and I can replicate the behavior, partially.  Is CloudFront configured to use this bucket as an "S3" origin, or a "Custom" origin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice that CloudFront does handle `+` in the URL now. So if you still have the distribution live, this URL should work:

https://d37uawng2qmzgo.cloudfront.net/images/natural+scenery+with+mountain+and+cloud.jpg

However though, if there are `+`s in the original filename, they need to be converted to `%2B` for the CloudFront URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help.